# Неверное определение пути к файлу процесса

Tags: c++, c, процесс

Есть код

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

VOID PrintProcessList(HANDLE CONST hStdOut) {
    PROCESSENTRY32 peProcessEntry;
    TCHAR szBuff[1024];
    DWORD dwTemp;
    TCHAR filepath[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD size = sizeof(filepath) / sizeof(TCHAR) - 1;
    HANDLE hproc;
    char text[MAX_PATH + 1];
    HANDLE CONST hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
        TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hSnapshot) {
        return;
    }
    bool tr;
    peProcessEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    Process32First(hSnapshot, &peProcessEntry);
    do {
        wsprintf(szBuff, L"=== %08X %s ===\r\n", peProcessEntry.th32ProcessID, peProcessEntry.szExeFile);
        WriteConsole(hStdOut, szBuff, lstrlen(szBuff), &dwTemp, NULL);
        hproc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, peProcessEntry.th32ProcessID);
        printf("%i, ", GetLastError());
        tr = QueryFullProcessImageNameW(hproc, 0, filepath, &size);
        printf("%i, %i\n", GetLastError(), tr);
        wcstombs(text, filepath, wcslen(filepath) + 1);
        puts(text);
        //printf("%s\n", filepath);
    } while (Process32Next(hSnapshot, &peProcessEntry));
    CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
}

INT main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    HANDLE CONST hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    PrintProcessList(hStdOut);
    system("pause");
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Не для всех процессов он показывает верное местоположение(есть и верные определения).

Вопрос: что я не так делаю в коде? Что нужно изменить, чтобы пути к файлам(ко всем без исключения) определялись верно?

Comment: Отладка, тестирование, правки if-ами. Больше никак.

Comment: Вы очень нагло используете `OpenProcess`, не каждый процесс вам это разрешит. Особенно системные процессы. Для таких прийдётся затыкать "дыры" if-ами.

Comment: @Lejko7  Прежде, чем что-то использовать, почитайте, наконец, описание этого. Вопрос следует закрыть.

Comment: **Process32First** безнадёжно устарела, и годится только для win95,98. Используйте [NtQuerySystemInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) вместо неё, она даёт гораздо больше информации за меньшее время и к-во действий.

Comment: Вот вам похожее на рабочий пример http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40626-list-processes-using-ntquerysysteminformation/